# Gmap: how to draw squares on Earth (lat, lon)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I was trying to draw a square

```
rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle();
var rectOptions = {
    strokeColor : "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity : 0.8,
    strokeWeight : 2,
    fillOpacity : 0,
    map : map
};
rectangle.setOptions(rectOptions);
```

with a length of 0.005'

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {

    var center = map.getCenter();
    rectangle.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat()-0.005, center.lng()-0.005),
            new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat()+0.005, center.lng()+0.005)));
});
```

but I realized the square is a square near equator, but is quite deformed elsewhere, 
is there a function that decreases with latitude to get the equivalent length of the longitude? thx for the help

**edit**:  square's height = cos(lat)width

Comment: You need to define **exactly** how you are measuring the square you want to see. Sides of equal *angular* "length" will at least look rectangular on the map. If you want your square to have real right-angle corners *on the globe*, then the sides will splay on the map and the edge nearest the pole will look too long. Your formula is probably `dX(a)=cos(a)*dY` but I don't think that will produce a square by any definition.

Comment: thx works var center = map.getCenter();
  var c = Math.cos(center.lat()* Math.PI / 180);
  rectangle.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat()-c*rad, center.lng()-rad),
    new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat()+c*rad, center.lng()+rad)));

Comment: @andrew, thx again, also to convert this angle in kms, it's theta*6371*Pi/180 right? because it's seems big in the map

Comment: Circumference of the Earth averages 40075km, so conversion is `(theta/360)*40075`km for great-circle distance. I still don't know what you're actually doing, or what you are going to end up with.

Comment: having pretty squares like this 1000km one http://i45.tinypic.com/x6a04.png

Comment: btw it's more an equator circumference?, which differs from longitude circumference

Comment: Google Maps uses a variant of the Mercator Projection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps#Map_projection). Maybe there's something you can use in the formulas for that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Formulae_for_distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from Andrew Leach comment:

```
function drawSquare(position=new google.maps.LatLng(41, 36.12), radius=0.001){

    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle();
    var rectOptions = {
        strokeColor : "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity : 0.8,
        strokeWeight : 2,
        fillOpacity : 0
    };
    rectangle.setOptions(rectOptions);

    var c = Math.cos(position.lat()* Math.PI / 180);
    rectangle.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(position.lat()-c*radius/2, position.lng()-radius/2),
            new google.maps.LatLng(position.lat()+c*radius/2, position.lng()+radius/2)));
    return rectangle;
}
```